# Pass argument to function in eclipse?

Tags: python, eclipse

I go into File-properties-edit-arguments type a string. When run program I get no output.

```
def print(n):
    print n
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure you're calling the method from somewhere, typically a `main()` or `test()` function in the Python file.  Also, avoid using `print`, since that masks the actual statement/function.  (In Python 2.x, this won't even *run* - you *have* to name it something other than `print`.)

```
def main():
    print(raw_input("Will print something "))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```